# Second order differential equation of the pendulum system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Who was the first to derive second order differential equation representing a simple case pendulum? (Galileo, Newton, Huygens, Leibniz or someone else)?

$\ddot\theta = \sin(\theta)$

I personally suspect Huygens, however I do not have a proof.

Comment: Henry Kater in  1817.

Comment: @JCH: Source? Surely it must have been known *much* earlier than that, given that Newton and Huygens studied pendula already in the 17th century.

Comment: Judging from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens#Pendulums, it seems Huygens didn't quite get to the equation for the simple pendulum. But I'm thinking that it must at least have been known to people like Euler and Lagrange in the 18th century.

Comment: I also have to consider Robert Hooke who was the first to study conical pendulum.